# Knockoutjs ObservableArray Keeps Doubling in Size

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to understand some slightly odd behavior I am seeing in a page I am making using KnockoutJS.  An observable array seems to get duplicate items every time I clear and reapply bindings.  The quickest way to understand the problem is to look at this [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jamshall/fD5Kt/28/).  Just click any edit button several times, and watch this list grow!

The heart of the code for this demo is in the following method:

```
var _bindItemDetail = function (jsonData) {
        //clear existing bindings
        ko.cleanNode($("#itemdetails").get(0));

        // observables in selected item.
        _viewModel.SelectedItem(ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData));

        // Apply Bindings
        ko.applyBindings(_viewModel.SelectedItem, $("#itemdetails").get(0));
    };
```

The essence of what I am trying to achieve is to create a list and details page in one.  The list JSON is fetch on initial page load, and the detail JSON is fetched and bound to the "detail" html whenever an edit link is clicked.

In addition to solving the problem, I am trying to understand the behavior, and learn some lessons about how to clean up stale resources properly when using knockout.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your `_bindItemDetail` function, you are reapplying the bindings on your modified view where you already had replicated the elements.

```
var _bindItemDetail = function (jsonData) {
    //clear existing bindings
    ko.cleanNode($("#itemdetails").get(0));

    // observables in selected item.
    _viewModel.SelectedItem(ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData));

    // Apply Bindings
    ko.applyBindings(_viewModel.SelectedItem, $("#itemdetails").get(0));
};
```

`ko.cleanNode()` merely removes bindings from the elements, it doesn't revert the view back to its initial state.  In general, you should only ever call `ko.applyBindings` on a set of nodes once.  Doing it more than once, is just asking for problems.

Frankly you're not really making good use of knockout.  The majority of your code is using jquery to handle all the low-level details.  The point of using knockout is to not have to worry about those lower level details.

I've adjusted your fiddle a bit to make better use of knockout with less emphasis on using jquery.

In the view:

- Used the `click` binding to handle your `Edit` click events.
- Used the `with` binding to conditionally show the editor fields.  The `stopBindings` handler is not needed.

In the view model:

- Added the click handler `editClicked` to the view model.
- Removed jquery event bindings.
- Removed the `ko.cleanNode`/`ko.applyBindings` combo you had when binding items.  You shouldn't do that and you just don't need it, knockout will handle all that for you.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/fD5Kt/33/)

Comment: Thanks Jeff! That both solved my problem, and edjimicated me in the appropriate use of knockout. The "with" binding is an interesting one.  I previously figured it was just a convenience binding to refine the scope of the context.  However, it seems much more significant that that - especially in this type of circumstance. Muchas gracias.